# How to store vertical movement value in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, game-development

I'm trying to make a jump animation using a blend tree in unity2D.
I got the blend tree set up correctly I just need a way to keep track of the vertical movement value in order to change between the jump and fall animations.

here is the code and the blend tree:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb9Ns.png)
[Blend Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx64J.png)

thanks for the helpers :)

Comment: Please post your code not a screenshot

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post a snippet of your code instead of a screenshot hyperlink. Additionally, please specify the exact issue you are having.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a float that holds the vertical velocity of the player:

```
float yVel = rb.velocity.y;
anim.SetFloat("Y Velocity", yVel);
```

Just remember to keep it updated!

Good Luck!